# PHP JSON color change depending on value

Tags: php, json

I want to change the number color depends on number value from json object.

Example this is my json file.

```html
{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "521997295": {
            "global_rating": 4647
        }
    }
}
```

If the global rating number is lower than 1000 i want to display green. If it is higher red ect... It must be in php script. How do i do that? Thank you for help.

Comment: Change the color of what? Please improve the question to include... maybe php.

Comment: If the global_rating number is lower than 1000 i want to display green color font. If it is higher red ect... It must be in php script. How do i do that? Thank you for help.

Comment: You need to read data from JSON using PHP and then use conditional logic using if/else to do that.

Comment: Do you know how to read json from file? How to decode it to object or array?

Comment: Yes. From where you are getting this data? Any external API or JSON file?

Comment: Yes i know how to read json from file but i dont know the code to change the color of the value.

Comment: I get this data from here https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=demo&fields=global_rating&account_id=521997295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to use `json_decode()` function to read the JSON data as an object or array.

Then from the object or array, you will need to get the value of 'global_rating'.

After that, you can use conditional logic to do the things as you want. For example:

```
`<?php
if($global_rating < 1000) {
    // font-color = green
} else {
    // font-color = red
}
`
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can i use html color code instead of font-color = green? Example font-color = #FF0000

Comment: Yes, you will need to uncomment those lines and use HTML code to make the font color green or red.